# invalid_grant response from exchange of authorization code

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I am trying to authenticate my application to Google contacts API.  I have gone though the first step in the Oauth2 flow and have an authorization code.  I am trying to exchange this code for an access token and refresh token, but when i try to get Token from googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token receive with

> response : "invalid_grant" "Bad request" Error 400.

**My code**

```
try
        {
            Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            params.put("grant_type","authorization_code");
            params.put("code", authCode);
            params.put("client_id",CLIENTE_ID);
            params.put("client_secret",CLIENTE_ID_SECRETO);
            params.put("redirect_uri","http://localhost:8080/conob/api2/contatos/insert");

            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            for(Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet())
            {
                if(postData.length() != 0){
                    postData.append('&');
                }

                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(),"UTF-8"));
                postData.append('=');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()),"UTF-8"));
            }

            byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

            URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setUseCaches(false);
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", postData.toString().length() + "");
            con.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);


            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
                String accessToken = json.getString("access_token");

                return accessToken;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                System.out.println(buffer.toString());
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        return null;
```

Parameters output:

> grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&client_id=CLIENTE_ID&client_secret=CLIENTE_SECRET&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fconob%2Fapi2%2Fcontatos%2Finsert

I'm searching for many hours in many forums but not conclude a solution for my problem.

Basically, my app needs to insert new contact on a google accounts in company intranet.

**My question is what the response is "invalid_grant"?**

Good code and thanks since now;

Comment: What the reponse is "Bad Request" in this case, sorry :/

Comment: Any reason you are not using the [google api java client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client)

Comment: try and post it to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token not https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/toke

Comment: @bogl the question and issue were quite clear to me.  However since you where having issues understanding it I have edited his question.   Is it more clear now?

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow, Nicolas! The question is much more readable now,  thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In the [OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) spec, `"invalid_grant"` is sort of a catch-all for all error response related to invalid/expired/revoked tokens (auth grant or refresh token).

**common causes**

1. User has actively revoked access to our app
2. User has reset/recovered their Google password
   In December 2015, Google changed their default behavior so that password resets for non-Google Apps users would automatically revoke all the user's apps refresh tokens. This is not true for all apis contacts is not one of them but i thought i would note it anyway.

Apart from those, there's a myriad of other potential causes that could trigger the error:

3. Server clock/time is out of sync
4. Not authorized for offline access
5. Throttled by Google
6. Using expired refresh tokens
7. using an expired authorization code.
8. User has been inactive for 6 months
9. Incorrect or invalid refresh token
10. Use service worker email instead of client ID
11. Too many access tokens in short time
12. Client SDK might be outdated

**Endpoint**

I realize that the discovery document says `googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` but for some reason this end point does not always work try using `accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`

**redirect_uri_mismatch**

Means that the redirect uri you are sending with your request `http://localhost:8080/conob/api2/contatos/insert` is not one of the ones you have added in the Google developer console.  You need to go back to the google developer console and add this redirect uri.

Note you may want to consider working with the google people api its a much easier api to work with then the old google contacts api.

Comment: DalmTo thanks for help.

I tried change POST for https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token and nowthe error is:

_"error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",  "error_description": "Bad Request"_

I'm using my account for test the api, so Server/Clock time is correct, in consent screen the acess_type is offline, the authorization code is the response of my first user redirection.

Comment: Check my edit for solution to redirect_uri_missmatch

Comment: Is in the Dev console on Google Cloud, of any way, i really consider to use the People API, if have anyone suggestion for resolve de Uri_missmatch i thank.

Comment: THe way to resolve the redirect missmatch is to add the redirect uri to the client https://console.developers.google.com  This is the only way.  You simple go in edit your client add the proper redirect uri and it will work

Comment: See below the redirect uri granted of my Cliente_Secret.json:

`["http://localhost:8080/conob/api2/contatos/token",
"http://localhost:8080/conob/api2/contatos/insert",
"http://localhost:8080/conob/api2/contatos/insert/",
"http://localhost:8080/conob/api2/contatos/token/",
"http://127.0.0.1:8080/conob/api2/contatos/insert",
"http://127.0.0.1:8080/conob/api2/contatos/insert/"],
"javascript_origins":["http://localhost:8080"]}}`

Comment: adding it to your client secret json won't help it must be added to Google identity server  what you have listed is also http you are sending https.   it must exactly March what is registered in developers console under redirect URI.

Comment: Print of my console: [Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BY9_K8VypGAw6PSCy4Odjde8wevyJ4sK)